# pyInstaller doesn't import module in own package path

Tags: python, pyqt, pyinstaller

My current project path looks like this:

> TestProject\machine_learning\gui_iris_classifier

The main file, which should be packed into an .exe-file, is located there (`gui.py`) and also two more source files with some utility-functions I wrote (`iris_gui_v1.py` and `irisclassifier.py`)

`gui.py` contains imports from these two files:

```
from machine_learning.gui_iris_classifier.irisclassifier import IrisClassifier
from machine_learning.gui_iris_classifier.iris_gui_v1 import Ui_Dialog
```

and also more imports from `PyQt` and `sys`:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QMessageBox
```

I am using `pyinstaller v3.3.1`, `Windows 10 64-bit` and `Python 3.6.5 Anaconda`.

This is the command I am using for `pyinstaller`:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import PyQt5.sip --hidden-import machine_learning.gui_iris_classifier.irisclassifier gui.py
```

while I am in my project path (`TestProject\machine_learning\gui_iris_classifier>`).

The `warngui.txt` contains among others these two error messages:

> missing module named 'machine_learning.gui_iris_classifier' - imported
>   by
>   C:\Users**\PycharmProjects\TestProject\machine_learning\gui_iris_classifier\gui.py
>
> missing module named machine_learning - imported by
>   C:\Users**\PycharmProjects\TestProject\machine_learning\gui_iris_classifier\gui.py

If I try to execute the generated .exe-file I get this error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "gui.py", line 3
>
> from machine_learning.gui_iris_classifier.irisclassifier import IrisClassifier
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'machine_learning'
>
> [5648] Failed to execute script gui

I don't understand why `pyInstaller` is unable to find the module even though it is in the same folder `gui.py` is in?

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Move the module `gui.py` to the folder`TestProject`

and execute in it:

`pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole gui.py`

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
The list of missing modules in `warngui.txt` is now much longer but there are no modules mentioned I directly import. The generated `.exe` file is 386MB in size. If i try to execute it on the command line, I don't get any errors but after a few seconds a window with message `Fatal Error! Failed to execute script gui` appears and my program doesn't open.